# Use of Angular elements inside angular app

Tags: angular, angular-elements

I would like to use angular elements for widgets here.

I went through the [angular.io example](https://angular.io/guide/elements#example-a-popup-service)  and also [angular-aio-src](https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/aio/src/app/custom-elements)

I am missing something here. Here is the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-elements-tryouts).

I am getting this error :

`Component ContentNotAvalilableComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.`

All the examples I have seen , are created as separate modules/ manual bootstrapping is done to embed that module. But I am trying something like angular aio does. load angular elements lazily with AppComponent bootstrapped. Not sure whats going wrong here?

Comment: `CustomElementsModule` is missing the declaration and the export of the `ContantNotAvailableComponent`

Comment: Yeah but since, it is a custom element , I have added it as part of `entryComponents` array.

Comment: You need anyway to declare it in some modules. If you just add the component to the array of declaration in the `CustomElementsModule` your code will works fine.

Comment: Yeah it works that way. But my custom element is still not working . The element tag is appended, but still the content is not displayed.

Answer (score 1):

import javascript in index.html

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs@2.1.3/custom-elements-es5-adapter.js"></script>
```

But see this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-build-plus